# changing variable names in a loop in fortran

Tags: fortran90

I am trying to make a loop that will let the user create multiple matrices in which they have declared the size of the matrix as in the number of columns and rows.  I have created the first part of this loop, but my issue is creating a variable whose name will change so that the matrix that was previously created in the loop will not be overwritten.  I then have to multiply all the differnt matrices together.

DO n=1:number          !number is the number of matrices that need to be created

WRITE(*,*)'Enter number of rows the matrix has'

READ(*,*)r

WRITE(*,*)'Enter number of columns'

READ(*,*)

REAL, DIMENSION(r,c) :: "here I need a changing variable name so it isn't overwritten every time."

Comment: Please share the code you have so far

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't dynamically generate new variables. It seems more like you just want to make each new variable an element of an array. Allocate an array with size equal to the number of loop iterations. It might get tricky if the variables are all 2d arrays of different dimensions, but you could certainly wrap it in some kind of structure.

Comment: I have to do partial products with the different matrices can I still do matrix multiplication if they are all elements of the same array.

Comment: @SpencerMickus yes, if the 2d arrays are all the same size and you can just build up a 3d array in your loop. Later in your program you can index out the particular 2d array you need to do the multiplication. Try thinking about the 3d array as just storage, and pull out matrices into temporary 2d array variables later.

Comment: I think He will have to create one 3D array and two arrays to hold the size of each matrix. like `A(500, 500, number)`   `length_x(number)` `length_y(number)`, where 500 is the maximum number of rows and columns. Just an example.